# Split text data into one column for several rows in Google Sheets/Excel

Tags: google-sheets, split, transpose

So I have data as follows:

```
text
A,B,C
A
B,D
```

In Google Sheets, I would like to take each of the rows above, parse by the `,` and make each entry a row.

So final outcome looks like this:

```
A
B
C
A
B
D
```

So here is what I have right now:

```
=TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(B1, ","))
```

And this will result in:

```
A
B
C
```

But I need to do this for all rows in one column..... so how can I replicate the above formula to make each of these entries **its own row in one column**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given the strings to be concatenated in B1 downwards (as your example suggests), you can simply JOIN the individual cells with commas then SPLIT the lot:

```
=transpose(split(join(",",B1:B),","))
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid any limitations on string length:

```
=ArrayFormula(query(flatten(iferror(split(A2:A,","))),"where Col1 is not null"))
```

[image]